# How do I get a UIView which displays text to behave like a UILabel when bounds change?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uilabel

I have a UIView in which I need to draw text in drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    ...
    [@"some text" drawAtPoint:somePoint withFont:someFont];
    ...
}
```

Because the text requires special formatting, I cannot just use a UILabel.

It looks fine until I rotate the device. Then the size of my custom UIView changes (in the parent view's `layoutSubviews` method), and the text becomes stretched in one direction and squished in the other.

When I replace my view with a UILabel, the text always looks great, even when the bounds of the view changes.

How can I get my view to exhibit the same behavior as UILabel?

Some things I have looked into, but have yet to have success with:

- Set the view's layer's needsDisplayOnBoundsChange to YES.
- Set the view's contentStretch to CGRectZero.
- Call setNeedsDisplay in my view's layoutSubviews.

Maybe I'm not doing one of these things right. Has anyone else run into this?

**Update:** As recommended in James Huddleston's answer, I set the `contentMode` property of the view to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`, which got me part of the way there. The text now appears correct at the conclusion of the animation. However, at the start of the animation the text gets squished/stretched to fit the end dimensions and then gets unsquished/unstretched over the course of the animation. This is not the case with UILabel.

Comment: Excuse me, but how do you draw the text?

Comment: tia: Good point, I should have explained that. I've clarified in the question.

Comment: 6 years later - Did you find a solution for this (when using your own custom class that inherits from UIView directly) ?

Comment: I don't think so :) It's probably something simple, but I didn't look into it much farther.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the `contentMode` property of your view to `UIViewContentModeRedraw`.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that was hidden in there with the other content modes. With contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw the text now appears correct at the conclusion of the rotation. However, the text does warp during the transition. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think the way the animation works is that it has your `drawRect` method draw the post-rotation view at the post-rotation size, and then it scales that view on-the-fly (without calling `drawRect` again) to create the animation. So, if the post-rotation size of your view is smaller than the pre-rotation size, it will essentially draw your view at that smaller size, but then scale it up (and probably pixelate it) as the starting point for drawing the animation. Of course, any layout changes will be animated also. Does that make sense with what you're seeing?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm seeing. The thing is, UILabel doesn't do that. It just immediately sizes and positions the view at its post-rotation frame and draws the text accordingly. It doesn't get animated at all.

Comment: Perhaps `UILabel` gets special treatment during animation. Sorry ... I don't know a workaround for custom drawing.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work OK:

```
self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
self.contentStretch = CGRectMake(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5);
```

And then ensure that the bottom-right pixel is the background color. To do that, I put one pixel of padding around the contents of the view. It seems like UILabel doesn't have the one pixel border restriction, so it must be doing something different. But as far as I can tell, this has the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

There is some source code created by Kevin Ballard called FontLabel. ([code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/source/browse/trunk/external/FontLabel/?r=1426))

The good thing about this, it subclasses UILabel and you can use your own Font ;)

//EDIT: ok ok, as told I will update my answer to recommend subclassing UILabel `"to get all the UILabel goodness"` ^^

Comment: UILabel already lets you use your own font though. This is for use with cocos2d, which is rendering in OpenGL. Thanks though.

Comment: no you cant draw fonts that not in the framework. with this framework you can also draw UILabel with custom fonts that you have manually included in your project, lets say mySampleFont.ttf ;) // edit: or is even this possible with the default UILabel? if so please give me a sample code

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood what you meant by using your own font. Prior to iOS 3.2 and 4.0 you couldn't use your own font. You can with the newer versions of iOS, but I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: So, I initially dismissed this answer, but... it turns out I can just subclass UILabel for my custom view and get the effect I'm looking for! It works perfectly. Well, after I set contentMode = UIViewContentModeTopLeft, since it looked funny otherwise in my specific situation. iPortable: update your solution with a recommendation to just subclass UILabel to get all the UILabel goodness and I'll award you the bounty. I'm really wishing I could split the bounty among all the answerers though :(.

Comment: why did you un-ticked the answer? something wrong? probably cause I upvoted all other?

Answer (score 1):

Use a UIWebView

Sounds a bit overkill but it seems the recommended way to get formatted text that's more complicated than a UILabel can cope with.

Comment: Yeah, way overkill for my use case :). Particularly because I have everything working perfectly except this one detail.